# Is it a good way to put multiple user controls in a single page

Tags: c#, wpf, user-controls

My wpf application only contains one window, it allows user to see different views through click buttons in the window or other operations. Now, I put all of the user controls in the window, and when user click button or through other operations to check views, I use visibility to display or hide the user controls, I'm not sure if it is a good way, anybody has ideas?

Comment: That's completely fine. If you are using PRISM, you can inject views at runtime in regions.

Comment: @James you don't have to create all your controls. You can use `ContentControl` with set of `DataTemplates`, one for different view model [type](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.datatemplate.datatype(v=vs.110).aspx), and then just change `Content` of your `ContentControl` and it will pick up view automatically and create if for you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Answer is bit subjective. For few controls it may be okay. But it may not be a good way if you have lots of controls and based on some condition you hide show them. This will make the code unmaintable and error prone as you are some way maintaining the state.

Whey not use some template selector to switch between templates or change views depending on some state/navigation requirement. You can do that using MVVM framework like prism easily.